# Troubleshoot simple jquery expand/collapse with iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a div containing 3 divs, each containing an iframe. The 3 internal divs are 115px tall, and when you click on "view more" for each one, they all collapse, and the one then slides down to 200px.

I would like when that 200px tall one is clicked again, it will collapse and they will ALL slide down back to 115px, kind of like resetting it?

I spent 2 hours last night trying to figure it out and I'm SURE it's simple, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :/

Here's the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/zUDBN/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/zUDBN/2/)

Comment: I cleaned up the HTML of you jsfiddle a bit. Why do you have classes "partner three", "partner two"... Aren't they all partners? Also, WHERE do you want the user to click on the expanded div to reset all the divs?

Comment: ok, I got it working, updating the jsfiddle.

Comment: The HTML was just copy pasted from something I'm working that is a test site, the HTML will be cleaner in the final product, and I've got some CSS styles for divs with a class one/two/or three. 

I want someone to click on "Show more reviews" to expand that one, and click the SAME "show more reviews" to slide it down and 'reset' it. (ofc the 'show more' will say something like 'show-less' in the final product)

Comment: ok, no problem. If you can understand the difference between using .click()  and .on() then you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zUDBN/5/ There were two issues. The first is that you needed this code `$('.partner-wrap').slideDown("slow");` when you clicked on an item that was already selected. The second was that you were binding wrong. When you do this: `$('a.normal').click(...);` that will bind that function call to the objects returned by that selector on page load. After page load it doesn't matter what the selector is anymore. So that function was firing whenever the links were clicked regardless of whether they had the "normal" or "showing" class. Your second selector wasn't working for the same reason: `$('a.reviews-trigger.showing').click(...);`

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarification on the binding issue. I hope that made sense.

Comment: You could use this jquery function to esentially listen for changes in the dom and bind events: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I think i've got it. That's a valuable tip though, I was unaware of that, thanks a lot! Should save me tons of time in the future :)